# karma phantomjs not capturing in docker container

Tags: docker, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm having trouble getting phantomjs to capture karma in an alpine docker container. I'm using node 6.10.2. I've installed phantomjs alpine from [here](https://github.com/Overbryd/docker-phantomjs-alpine/releases). I'm using the following versions:

```
"karma": "^1.6.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-mocha": "^1.0.1",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
"karma-webpack": "^2.0.3",
```

Inside my container when I run my tests I see the following output. (timestamps removed)

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v1.6.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /workspace/karma-1981971
DEBUG [launcher]: /usr/bin/phantomjs /workspace/karma-1981971/capture.js
WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
```

It then fails 2 times before exiting.

When I look at the contents of the tmp file `capture.js` it shows it is trying to open `localhost:9876/?id=18274999` and inside my container I try to `wget http://0.0.0.0:9876/` which does indeed succeed.

So I am very confused why PhantomJs fails to capture when I can indeed connect from within my container.

How should I go about debugging this? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem in my build. I think using node 6.10.2 is the issue because I'm not seeing it happen on node 6.9.4

Comment: You are not using alpine node then